# Javascript D3 line generator generating 1 line for each data point in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a d3 script which is supposed to create and update a line using d3.line().

However, it is currently generating one curve for every data point.

The data is in the form
`let data = [{"x": 1,"y": 2}, {"x": 2,"y": 4}, {"x": 3,"y": 6}]`
(data can be changed dynamically and the function will be called to update the line)

The script :

```
let line = d3.line()
                .x(d => xScale(d["x"]))
                .y(d => yScale(d["y"]))
                .curve(d3.curveCardinal); 

function updateLine(data){
    let g1 = svg.selectAll("path.line").data(data);
    g1
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr("class", "line")
    .merge(g1)
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#348")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px");
}
```

When I inspected the HTML, there are multiple instances of the correct curve being drawn. As the dataset contains 200 data points, 200 lines were drawn (all of the lines are correct).

I tried googling and can't seem to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the multiple lines by adding a small change to the script, so that only one line is drawn.

```
let line = d3.line()
                .x(d => xScale(d["x"]))
                .y(d => yScale(d["y"]))
                .curve(d3.curveCardinal); 

function updateLine(data){
    let g1 = svg.selectAll("path.line").data(**[**data**]**);
    g1
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr("class", "line")
    .merge(g1)
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#348")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px");
}
```

Any idea why this works?